# Multiple Python Distribution on Linux system

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I work on Linux 16.04 which ships with both Python 2 and Python 3 pre-installed. I used to work with this pre-installed core Python distribution for some time now and have added a few packages to the distribution using pip. Lately I have been planning to install the Anaconda python distribution as well without disturbing my core python distribution but I am not sure how the two distributions will work together on the same Linux System

1. If there is a package installed both in my core and Anaconda distribution , will that lead to any kind of conflict ?
2. What will run if I just python3 on the terminal ? The python of the core distribution or the Anaconda distribution ?
3. Can I run both instances of Python simultaneously ?

Comment: I would suggest looking into [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for managing python versions beyond the basic system `python` and `python3`.

Comment: @TravisClarke Anaconda can just as easily manage different Python versions, IMO there is no need to suggest an entirely different software when the software the OP wants to use accomplishes the function just as well.

Comment: @darthbith - I understand your point. Still, I don’t think that it is *harmful* information to suggest a python version manager, or even virtual environments for that matter, as an alternative. Unless of course I attempted to formulate it as an answer. My intention is simply to inform the OP, and future visitors, of a minimalist option for juggling multiple Python versions with nominal conflict.

Comment: @TravisClarke Your comment read to me like "Oh, you use Windows? You should really use Linux" type of comments :-) Anyways, as you say, its good to know about alternatives, particularly for future visitors to the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, the packages installed in the system Python directories and the Anaconda directories are separate. There may be a conflict if you installed packages using the `--user` option to pip, which installs packages into the `~/.local` directory on Ubuntu. However, this will only be a problem if you try to use the same version of Python (3.4 or 3.6 or...).
2. Which Python will run depends on what you have set for your `PATH` environment variable. You can check the value of this variable in the terminal by typing `echo $PATH`. If, for example, you type `python3` in the terminal, the shell will run the first executable file named `python3` in the `PATH`. If your path looks like `/home/user/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`, then the Anaconda Python will be found first.
3. You can choose which Python you want to run at a given time by using the full path to that Python executable, for instance, `/usr/bin/python3`, `/usr/bin/python2`, `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python`, `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/python`. In general, there is no problem with doing this, and there will be no conflicts. The only problem you might have is that you have to install 2 copies of the packages you want to use (one for the system Python, one for Anaconda) if you want to use both versions of Python.

   a. Addition from @sascha:

   > When using anaconda's environments, you usually would use [`activate`](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) to select one environment (e.g. terminal-tab 1: `source activate py2`, terminal-tab 2: `source activate py3`; then calling python or pip or ... will behave differently in these terminal-tabs)